# Error when set "disabled" config to customized Ext.field.Text

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I have a customized text box which gives me a textbox with a button in textfield next to it.
(run the code you'll see what I mean).
The only problem is that if I set the disabled state to false I get an error saying:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValue'`
But if I set it to true all is good.

This is my code:

```
    var disabled = false;

    var _oInput = Ext.create("Ext.field.Text", {
        flex: 8,
        labelWidth:0,
        labelAlign: "right",
        value: self.psValue,

    });

    var _oSenchaObject = Ext.create("Ext.field.Text",{
        label: "test",
        disabled: disabled,  //This gives me the error
        component: {
          xtype: 'container', 
          layout: 'hbox', 
          items: [
              _oInput, 
              {
                xtype: 'button', 
                flex: 1, 
                text: '...',
                //disabled: disabled,
              }
          ]
        },
    });

    var formPanelComment = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title:"Comments",
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: "Comments",
            items: [
                _oSenchaObject
            ]
        }]
    });
```

Comment: seems that your code snippet for `_oSenchaObject` is missing something near `"Ext.field"...`, pls edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. :)

This is because of a conflict when you've defined your "custom" `textfield` (containing a normal textfield with an inner button).

Have a look at your code snippet, the line which gives you an error is:

```
var _oSenchaObject = Ext.create("Ext.field.Text",{
        ...
        disabled: disabled,  //This gives me the error
        component: {
          ...
        },
    });
```

Here, `disabled` config is applied to children components (which are defined in `component` config), but Sencha Touch does not know how to correctly disable your textfield, disable your inner container (which contains another field and button). I guess it's something like a bug, or framework limitation.

So, the solution is just set `disabled` config to each of your single children. In the example above, just move that line to `_oInput`'s config.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This does get rid of the error and disables the inputfield/button, but the problem I am having with this solution is that the design of the label does not indicate the field being disabled. Normal disabled fields get a gray(ish) tint. This one doesn't when I use your solution. This is of course because I set the label of the outer textfield (and that one is not disabled because of the earlier problem).

Comment: what about defining `label` right in your `_oInput`? It's natural because the label belongs to that field

Comment: If I do that the label width differs with the other "normal" text fields. This is because of the width being relative to the screen-width and with the button added, the label is shorter by default.